# certification hardware

Tags: hardware, hardware-certification

we are a tunisian manufacturer "IGL Industrie" we have our Brand " versus ".
We need certified our desktop PC  with ubuntu.
have you any information about process ?
Please help us
best regards

Answer (score 0):

Start at https://certification.ubuntu.com.

There is a link on that page for manufacturers.